# How programmatically get Credit memo Comment History?

Tags: magento2

I want to get credit memo history programmatically by credit memo id how can I get using the Credit memo id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way:

```
protected $collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Comment\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory 
) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}
```

Now try following code:

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Comment\Collection $collection */
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$collection->setCreditmemoFilter($creditmemoId);
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    echo $item->getComment();
}
```

Comment: Please @Sohel Rana help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/322611/85907