# Magento 2 Email template How to add Controller Path

Tags: magento2, controllers, email-templates

I want to add controller path in Email template.I have create custom email template using programmatically.

This is my code :-

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<table>
    <tr class="custom-gdpr">
        <p><strong>Hello {{var name}} , </strong></p>
        <p>You Are Confirom Delete Your Account in Our Store. </p>
        <p>If {{trans '<a href="Here I want to controller URL">Yes</a>'|row}} Or  {{trans '<a href="Here I want to controller URL">No</a>'|row}}</p>
        <strong>Thank you</strong>
    </tr>
</table>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

I want to Following link add in **`For Example:-`**

```
xyz.com/routername/controllername/action/customerid/encryptedid..
```

Please Advice me How to add Dynamic URL,

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way:

```
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
```

Now when you send transactional email, you need to pass values as DataObject Object. Ex.

```
'data' => new DataObject($post)
```

Where $post is an array.

Set the variable like:

```
->setTemplateVars($variables)
```

*Check the Magento_Contact module as an example. Specially the following class:*

***1. vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php***

```
private function sendEmail($post)
{
    $this->mail->send(
        $post['email'],
        ['data' => new DataObject($post)]
    );
}
```

***2. vendor/magento/module-contact/Model/Mail.php***

```
public function send($replyTo, array $variables)
{
    /** @see \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::validatedParams() */
    $replyToName = !empty($variables['data']['name']) ? $variables['data']['name'] : null;

    $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
    try {
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->contactsConfig->emailTemplate())
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars($variables)
            ->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
            ->addTo($this->contactsConfig->emailRecipient())
            ->setReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName)
            ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
    } finally {
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
    }
}
```

***3. vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/email/submitted_form.html***

```
{{var data.email}}
```

Comment: Please check this link and help me  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/324550/85907